# Laragon Apache fails to start after switching to PHP 5.6.9

Tags: php, apache, laragon

Anyone know how to solve this? This error comes out when I switched from PHP 7.2.19 to PHP 5.6.9:

[image: Error message]

Comment: post your error instead image

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem and took a few hours to solve

just download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012

and it will work